# MySql quick user select

Tags: mysql, function, select

I have a Users table and I'm getting user details (usual way) with id.

This is how I'm getting user details;

```
select id,kullaniciadi,FotoGet(K.Foto,K.Gender) from kullanicilar K where id=1;
```

`FotoGet` function always returning string value like 'Photos/ssss.jpg'

So far I have not trouble to use this way but I'm wondering how can I do this with a single function?
Like

```
set @uid=1;
Select UserGet(@uid);
```

I will put the `id` inside parentheses and the function will run my select query and return all user detail columns. `id`, `kullaniciadi`, `FotoGet(K.id,K.Foto,K.Gender)`

Can I use this way to get details?

Comment: Why -1 ? :( it just a no high-level question. Isn't what we do? Asking a question? Come on guys, please dont judge for this question.

Comment: Don't let the downvotes bother you. There's always some grouch out there who thinks the question is invalid, but that reflects on him or her, more than on you. Maybe he or she just doesn't like MySQL in general and doesn't think anyone should use it or ask about it. Who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MySQL stored function cannot return multiple columns, it can only return a single scalar value.

But you could design a stored procedure that returns a result set:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UserGet(uid INT)
  SELECT id, kullaniciadi, FotoGet(K.Foto,K.Gender) FROM kullanicilar K WHERE id=uid;
```

Then call it like so:

```
CALL UserGet(1234);
```

It returns a result set just like a `SELECT` query would.

---

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UserGet(IN uid INT, IN column_name VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, ', column_name, ' FROM kullanicilar K WHERE id=?');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  SET @uid = uid;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @uid;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Call it like so:

```
CALL UserGet(1234, 'kullaniciadi');
```

Remember that it's your responsibility to write code to pass a valid column name as the procedure argument. If you allow untrustworthy content to be passed, then it might be an SQL injection vulnerability.

---

Re your additional comment:

This should work fine:

```
CALL UserGet(1234, 'FotoGet(Foto,Gender)');
```

Comment: Can i get row name in argument? Like 
CREATE PROCEDURE UserGet(uid INT, rows)
  SELECT rows FROM kullanicilar K WHERE id=uid;

Comment: You must mean column name? Yes, but that's more complex. You would have to use PREPARE and EXECUTE, and then you have to learn how to protect your code from SQL injection. I don't mean to be insulting, but if you don't know the difference between "row" and "column" then you're probably not ready for that yet. I recommend you stick with fetching a fixed set of columns for now.

Comment: I'm so sorry, my english is not so good. Im thinking column(in my lang. is sütun) but however i wrote row :(.

and can u give me a example for getting column name in argument

Comment: @traBolics, see example above.